# Issue on URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I get this URL "R+C%20Seetransport%20Hamburg" passing the query string using Javascript , but i need to get the URL in this format "R%2bC+Seetransport+Hamburg" using C#

Code Used:

```
        var listname = $(this).text();
        var listname1 = listname.trim();

        // var senderElement = e.target;
        var afullUrl = '<%=SPContext.Current.Web.Url%>';
        var aurl = afullUrl + "/_Layouts/15/RUM/View_Details.aspx?List_Name="+listname1;

        window.location = aurl;
```

Comment: I would reword this question. Start by listing the actual input filename you're starting with. Then list the expected output followed by the actual output and your code. Take C# out of the picture because you're really trying to do this in javascript I think. Or if you want to make this a C# question start with "Here's what I'm receiving in C#, how can I make it look like this?" and show the code you've used to try and convert it.

Comment: I think you just need to decode server side

Comment: when i decode the query string using this code HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["List_Name"].ToString()); i get like this "R C Seetransport Hamburg" but i need "R+C Seetransport Hamburg" like this. If i Encode the same code  "R+C+Seetransport+ Hamburg" i get in this format

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for %20 to be replaced by + sign then you can do the following:

```
var listname1 = listname1.replace(/%20/g, "+");
```

The %20 represents a white space. And %2b represents +(plus sign).

The problem seems to lie in the Urldecoding. You can also try decodeURIComponent() for removing %20 back to whitespace.